# Disable user zoom in cordova app for windows phone 8

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hybrid

On windows phone my app is zoom-able and if I do a swipe top on the body I see white like on the browser. I already used meta no resizable and user zoom fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing the same issue:

```
body{
    touch-action: pan-y; /* disable all actions except vertical scrolling */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `initial-scale=1`, `maximum-scale=1`, to the **viewport tag**?

Setting the CSS property: `zoom: 1` can maybe fix your issue.
Let me know.

Example:

```
* {
    zoom: 1;
}
```